# Preform IIS Basic Authentication through code instead of browser popup

Tags: asp.net, iis, basic-authentication

What i'm trying to do is:
Receive username and password via form and authenticate them with IIS using basic authentication.
The thing is, I want to do this without the built in browser popup.
Is there a way to override the popup and authenticate through code?
My website is in ASP.NET and i'm using IIS7. 
Thanks to all helpers!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to write the server side authentication your selv or create a client that connects to some web site using basic authentication?

Comment: I mean I want to write the server side authentication my self.
Basically what i need to do is get a username and password from a form and authenticate them through iis basic authentication. but they have to come from a form, not from the default browser popup.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the credentials in the URL.  See for instance https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters.  Note the remark in that question that it doesn't work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Basic authentication uses a base64 encoded string containing [username:password] in the http authentication header.

You can simply add this to your request using jQuery's header function before performing the request. But wrong credentials would still cause a pop up.

Comment: Thanks fauster. I'm not quite sure of one thing:
what url am i supposed to be posting the authorization reqeust to?

Comment: Putting it in the header means that you don't have to alter the url.